# Reverse test coverage

Tags: unit-testing, build-automation, code-coverage

I am looking for the way to automate the following task.

Given the coverage report,  find out which tests cover particular method / function.  Even better if I can specify specific class and line number.

The running time is not very imoprtant as long as it could be done within few hours. I am thinking of running each test one by one and collecting the coverage records in a database.  Just wandering if there is someone out there who faced a similar problem and has a ready made solution.

Our project is medium sized with about 100 unit test cases.

P.S.  To clarify our project is Java based,  but I am also looking to see what other platforms have in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) (.NET Code Coverage) already supports this feature for MSTest, NUnit and xUnit (other test frameworks can be added). Running time is only fractionally longer than running normally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately we are Java based with JUnit / Cobertura.  But I also was looking for the general solution as well.

Comment: There is no general solution - OpenCover tracks the tests that are running and marks up the sequence point visits against the test as well as the generic visit; perhaps a similar trick could be engineered into Cobertura.

The alternative is to run each test individually and track the coverage for each test (and visitied sequence points (assuming a similar markup to .NET) how you would merge the results however would be up to you.