# How to navigate from code coverage to unit test or test method in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

How can I recognize in IntelliJ which JUnit test covered the line (code). I already know how to generate the code coverage data with IntelliJ, in order to be sure 100% of my lines are covered. However, I have a case where I want to navigate in reverse.

So, after running tests with coverage, I need to know which JUnit test or test method covered a specific line of code, simply navigating from covered line to the test that covered it.

I'm also aware about navigating to test subject (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), but that does not help me. What would help me is exactly which line of tests/methods covered the code line.

Note: I am using JUnit and IntelliJ or JaCoCo for code coverage.

Comment: "so after running tests with coverage i need to know which junit test or test method covered a special line of code" Almost definitely not possible.

Comment: Thanks, It was good if it was possible!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse test coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346224/reverse-test-coverage)